# Word for "something that is only useful if all needed parts are present"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to find a word, if it exists, for something that can not be useful by itself, but only in combination with all the other needed elements.

For example, individual parts of a computer, a graphics card or central processing unit for example are practically useless by themselves. However, when put together, they become useful as they make the computer functional.

Comment: Do you have a context? Give us a sentence to say for which exact meaning you are trying to use this word.

Comment: An appeal merely for synonyms of 'essential' would be off-topic.

Comment: @fev The context could be any similar instance of my description of the computer parts and describing parts like this. I am not sure how I can provide a sentence to highlight the exact meaning.

Comment: Sounds like _Blackman's Law of limiting factors._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a part cannot work on its own it means it is not self-sufficient, not autonomous, not independent. If you look at the ***[opposite of autonomous](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/autonomous.html#C0-3)*** you get ***dependent or interdependent***. You may also think of *incomplete* or *complementary*. But from your question it is not clear if an adjective would be ok as an answer (which you could add next to *part* or *component*)

I am afraid ***essential*** does not go here, because though it does not state that the component is self-sufficient, the emphasis falls on the fact that the component is significant for the whole, not on the fact that *it cannot function without the other parts*.

Comment: 'Interdependent' is probably closest, but really refers to all parts (including the one focused on) being needed, not just (for the one focused on) useful. The lens cap again.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, you are right, _interdependent_ has a collective meaning. But giving different words from the semantic field of this connotation might help the OP corner his word :) May I take this opportunity to ask you, what does the expression "lens cap" mean? It sounds funny and worth learning.

Comment: This shows why specimen sentences are considered necessary (and why many consider answers to questions not providing these wrong) for SWRs. When it comes to merely listing synonyms (often for the nth time), not knowing exactly what flavour would please OP, it detracts from the site's credibility.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: May I take this opportunity to ask you, what does the expression "lens cap" mean? It sounds funny and worth learning.

Comment: When I was young, free online dictionaries were undreamed of. Now, with a few keystrokes, most people can look up compound nouns, find definitions ... in this case, buy replacement lens caps even. Very important for keeping the instrument's outer lens surface safe and clean, but a clean camera case say means you can still use the camera until a replacement arrives.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of electronic/spare parts, I would suggest 'not standalone' (adj) . Not single a word, though. For instance, a transistor cannot be a standalone part.

Answer (score 0):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/component) has the word

> **component**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1** A part or element of a larger whole, especially a part of a machine or vehicle.
>
> *If any one of these components fail, the whole system fails, certainly in an agricultural context.*

Although the definition does not specifically say "useless without other components", that is the meaning of the term: an essential part of the whole, incomplete in itself.

Comment: Aircraft have components in parallel in case one fails. I'd say the emphasis is on 'part' rather than 'essential part'. 'Component' would perhaps be a suitable answer on ELL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth your example demonstrates that the component *is* essential.

Comment: Not globally (essential to the plane's landing safely), therefore not in the default sense.

Answer (score -2):

Two words come to mind: both attribute absolute need to the component. An *essential* component is one without which the whole does not work. Similarly if it is *crucial*.

> *essential* = *something necessary, indispensable, or unavoidable*.
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essential

> *essential* = *a basic thing that you cannot live or succeed without*
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/essential

> *crucial* = *extremely important because many other things depend on it*
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crucial

You might also consider *indispensable*.

> *indispensable* = too important not to have; necessary
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indispensable)

Comment: An appeal merely for synonyms of 'essential' would be off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Where appeal? Why appeal? "would be" is mere speculation, isn't it? Are we not discouraged from mere opinion and speculation on this site?

Comment: I was wondering about the downvote; it seemed a bit harsh. Then I realised why someone had given it: you're considering item A to be essential, where OP says rather A is only of any use when B, C, D etc are in place. A lens cap is useful when you have a camera, but it's hardly essential. But the camera (lens, body, ...) is (within the specifications of 'necessary'). I've added a downvote.

Comment: Can’t win ‘em all I suppose. Thanks for the explanation. It may help someone.